# Is it true - $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{At}=\mathbf{0}_{n\times n}?$

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence

Let $A_{n\times n}$ be a diagonally dominant matrix such that each diagonal entry is negative and of absolute value strictly less than $1$, while each nondiagonal entry is nonnegative. Then is it true that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{At}=\mathbf{0}_{n\times n}.$$ I expect it is true, but I do not have a proof.

Is it true that $A$ is negative definite?

Comment: Did you check what comes out with  $A=-Id$?

Comment: Sorry, I have left one more condition that modulus of all the entries is less than 1.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: "Strictly less than one" is not important (can be done by scaling). In short: simply diagonally dominant (non-strict inequality) is not enough. For strictly diagonally dominant matrices it is true. If $A$ is Hermitian then it is also true that it is negative definite.

Comment: No, $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @A.G.! Could you please explain - how is it true for a strictly diagonally dominant matrix?

Answer (score 2):

For simply diagonally dominant it is not true. The counterexample is
$$
A=\left[\matrix{-1 & 1\\1 & -1}\right].
$$

For strictly diagonally dominant: assume that the matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}$ satisfies

- $a_{ij}\ge 0$, $i\ne j$
- $a_{ii}+\sum_{j\ne i}a_{ij}<0$

then by [Gerschgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) all the eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts, i.e. the matrix $A$ is stable, therefore, the result follows (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80581/exponential-bound-on-norm-of-matrix-exponential-of-linear-ode) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74710/stability-of-autonomous-linear-systems-of-odes?rq=1)).